# Javascript - .then() tries to return values before they're fetched

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am very new at javascript and asynchronous programming. I have a server.js that scrapes values from a job search website related to the given keyword. And a `JobDataFetcher` class to fetch them. 
 `JobDataFetcher` class:

```
class JobDataFetcher {
    constructor() {}

    async getSingleJobPostingCount(keyword) {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${keyword}`);
        const jobPostingCount = await response.json();
        return {
            keyword: keyword,
            count: jobPostingCount
        };
    }

    async getJobPostingCounts(keywords) {
        const jobPostings = [];
        let postingsProcessed = 0;

        keywords.forEach(keyword => {
            this.getSingleJobPostingCount(keyword)
                .then(jobPosting => {
                    jobPostings.push(jobPosting);
                    postingsProcessed++;
                    if (postingsProcessed === keywords.length) {
                        console.log(jobPostings);
                        return jobPostings;
                    }
                });
        });
    }
}
```

The `console.log(jobPostings)` inside this class gives me what i want, which is something like this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {keyword: "Angular", count: 266}
    1: {keyword: "React", count: 232}
    2: {keyword: "Vue", count: 98}
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

But when i'm using the `getJobPostingCounts()` method in my app.js, it returns undefined without waiting for data to be fetched:

```
    dataFetcher.getJobPostingCounts(keywords)
        .then(jobPostings => {
            console.log(jobPostings);
            // chart.destroy();
            // chart = ui.createChart(cardBodyUI, jobPostings);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I should probably put an `await` somewhere in `getJobPostingCounts(keywords)` class but after many tries i just could not figure out where.

Comment: `getJobPostingCounts` doesn't have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `forEach` callback runs synchronously, so once the `forEach` finishes, the `jobPostings` array hasn't been populated.

Map each `getSingleJobPostingCount` call to a Promise in an array, and call `Promise.all` on the array, which will resolve once each of those Promises in the array has resolved:

```
getJobPostingCounts(keywords) {
  return Promise.all(
    keywords.map(this.getSingleJobPostingCount)
  );
}
```

(no need for `getJobPostingCounts` to be `async`, since it doesn't use `await`)

The whole class seems unnecessary here, though - you're never using the instances, you're just using the class for the functions on its prototype. Consider using an object (or standalone functions) instead:

```
const dataFetcher = {
  async getSingleJobPostingCount(keyword) {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${keyword}`);
    const jobPostingCount = await response.json();
    return {
      keyword: keyword,
      count: jobPostingCount
    };
  },
  getJobPostingCounts(keywords) {
    return Promise.all(
      keywords.map(this.getSingleJobPostingCount)
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: You should probably bind `this` to your mapped function or make it a lambda

Comment: If `getSingleJobPostingCount` used the instance (the `this` keyword), it'd be useful, but it's not, so it wouldn't help

Comment: It's an anti-pattern though

Comment: Using a class at all here is the antipattern (the cause of the `this` not needing to be bound), which is why I recommended using a plain object instead.